# Posting big pictures in Open Graph Actions

Tags: facebook-opengraph, image

I am posting photos to Open Graph actions, they get resized to a thumbnail around 50*50 px .

In order to post a picture with activity, I use `image[]=URL` in [action parameters](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-actions/). However my thumbnail gets very small and in the timeline, people had to click on it and get to my site to see actual picture.

However, Foursquare recently implemented a Open Graph integration to Facebook. Now, if foursquare checkins have photos, they are posted to facebook in a high resolution and they appear in timeline like a real Wall Photo posted. (width = 300 , height = auto). (less resized)

How can we achieve that? Is that a deal between Foursquare and Facebook or is it publicly available feature of FB Open Graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is called User Generated Photos - its available to any app where the user actually took the picture on their device. It may not be used to make non-user generated photos large.

Here's the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/

Comment: Before this step, we have to do first (Provide trigger steps) step right?. How can we complete this step?. Please help me out this.

Comment: I have not been able to make User Generated photos work... :/